# two column layout with right column expanding to fill window

Tags: css

How in CSS can I make the `section` fluid when absolutely positioned?

```
<div class="layout">
  <aside>leftnav</aside>
  <section>content fluid here</content>
</div>

aside {
   width: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

section {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 200px;
   //fluid width to fill window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** With absolute positionning, just add:

```
section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0px; // this line
}
```

**End of edit.**

Use `float` on the `aside` tag and add a `margin-left` to the `section`:

```
aside {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

section {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention they are absolutely positioned.

Comment: @chovy Maybe put a fiddle with a minimum working example, would be easier to see exactly the context.